# New to AngularJS - what is missing in this simple example

Tags: angularjs

Here is my example:

```
<body ng-controller="ShoppingCart">
<div>
    <h3>Your online shopping cart</h3>
    <span>{{text.msg}}</span>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function ShoppingCart($scope){
        alert();            
        $scope.text ={ msg: 'alert message'};
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This doesn't display the message. What is missing?

Comment: If thats all then everything is missing. The ng-app directive, the whole module, the controller definition

Comment: there are a few things missing with your example as Nano pointed out - is this all the code you have or is there more? Please bear in mind, that the more detail you provide, the easier it becomes for the SO community to assist. Any basic Angular example shows you how to create a small app.

Comment: @Nano, this is Angular v1.0 - so it doesn't require the module or the controller definition

Comment: @NewDev what? angular need these definitions! how should angular know that `ShoppingCart` is a controller??

Comment: @Nano, http://plnkr.co/edit/XOz5TyMzY159a8l0u6IC?p=preview

Comment: Thanks buddies, I missed ng-app directive. now it is works fine for me.

Comment: Thats the first time i see a angular app defined like this o.o

Comment: I forget that, angular controller is identified by the ng-app directive

Comment: @Nano, like I said - this is only possible (at least by default) in early versions of Angular

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer** for your specific example, the only thing that is missing is the `ng-app` directive:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="ShoppingCart">
  {{text.msg}}
</body>
```

`ng-app` is a directive that specifies the root of your Angular app - Angular compiles everything under it.

**The longer answer** is that your example only works on older versions of AngularJS (prior to v1.3), that allowed for global functions like your `ShoppingCart` to be used as controllers.

This is now discouraged (and disabled by default in v1.3+).

The proper way is to define the app's module that registers a controller explicitly. That module is then used with `ng-app` directive:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("ShoppingCart", function($scope){
    $scope.text ={ msg: 'alert message'};
  })
```

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ShoppingCart">
    {{text.msg}}
  </div>
</body>
```